# How to plot the piecewise continuous points in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

My dataset is as follows:

```
G R Y
1 1 0
1 2 1
1 3 2
1 4 4
1 5 2
2 1 1
2 2 2
2 3 3
2 4 2
3 1 0
3 2 1
3 3 2
3 4 2
3 5 3
```

I want to know how to write the correct matplotlib code to plot the points as follows:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what you tried so far?

Comment: is this your data a csv/tsv?

Answer (score 1):

You could just split up your data according to the three sections you have, graph each group separately, and then attach the graphs together:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, sharey=True)
Y = [0, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3]
Y0 = Y[0:6]
Y1 = Y[5:10]
Y2 = Y[9:15]
axes[0].plot(Y0)
axes[1].plot(Y1)
axes[2].plot(Y2)
plt.ylim([0, 5])
subplots_adjust(wspace=0)
```

That will get you pretty close to what you need (though I admit some of the the x-axes could use a little extra formatting):

[image]

If I were you I would enter that line by line, hitting `plt.draw()` after every line of matplotlib code to see what exactly is going on.

Comment: Thanks, it is close to the figure that I want.