# Histogram hide empty bins

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I want to illustrate nicely how often (y-axis) a certain output (x-axis) occurs...
My code produces following plot:
[image: not precise]
It's not good, because the values are rounded to integers apparently, e.g., there are not over a 100 outputs with 100%, but actually most of them are 99% I think.

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

trajectoryIds = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0, 21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0, 28.0, 29.0, 30.0, 31.0, 32.0, 33.0, 34.0, 35.0, 36.0, 37.0, 38.0, 39.0, 40.0, 41.0, 42.0, 43.0, 44.0, 45.0, 46.0, 47.0, 48.0, 49.0, 50.0, 51.0, 52.0, 53.0, 54.0, 55.0, 56.0, 57.0, 58.0, 59.0, 60.0, 61.0, 62.0, 63.0, 64.0, 65.0, 66.0, 67.0, 68.0, 69.0, 70.0, 71.0, 72.0, 73.0, 74.0, 75.0, 76.0, 77.0, 78.0, 79.0, 80.0, 81.0, 82.0, 83.0, 84.0, 85.0, 86.0, 87.0, 88.0, 89.0, 90.0, 91.0, 92.0, 93.0, 94.0, 95.0, 96.0, 97.0, 98.0, 99.0, 100.0, 101.0, 102.0, 103.0, 104.0, 105.0, 106.0, 107.0, 108.0, 109.0, 110.0, 111.0, 112.0, 113.0, 114.0, 115.0, 116.0, 117.0, 118.0, 119.0, 120.0, 121.0, 122.0, 123.0, 124.0, 125.0, 126.0, 127.0, 128.0, 129.0, 130.0, 131.0, 132.0, 133.0, 134.0, 135.0, 136.0, 137.0, 138.0, 139.0, 140.0, 141.0, 142.0, 143.0, 144.0, 145.0, 146.0, 147.0, 148.0, 149.0, 150.0, 151.0, 152.0, 153.0, 154.0, 155.0, 156.0, 157.0, 158.0, 159.0, 160.0, 161.0, 162.0, 163.0, 164.0, 165.0, 166.0, 167.0, 168.0, 169.0, 170.0, 171.0, 172.0, 173.0, 174.0, 175.0, 176.0, 177.0, 178.0, 179.0, 180.0, 181.0, 182.0, 183.0, 184.0, 185.0, 186.0, 187.0, 188.0, 189.0, 190.0, 191.0, 192.0, 193.0, 194.0, 195.0, 196.0, 197.0, 198.0]
avgSolutionPercentages = [20.6256, 99.1448, 15.6764, 21.8231, 16.3733, 17.7502, 20.0055, 86.6873, 11.3105, 15.6693, 10.3449, 81.8921, 11.6745, 92.6031, 11.8787, 23.0229, 37.9636, 2.3903, 15.1727, 14.7088, 10.0426, 59.6758, 8.0042, 12.4174, 10.0585, 46.0567, 90.2376, 98.3273, 52.8645, 49.3027, 62.4136, 32.6199, 19.0642, 10.3319, 74.6157, 22.5771, 22.4118, 11.2017, 16.5053, 11.2021, 30.8376, 24.5255, 83.1072, 10.1529, 14.3991, 46.3459, 16.2137, 4.5773, 44.9549, 1.0719, 76.5605, 42.6589, 13.6209, 34.2856, 1.3574, 29.0465, 66.8146, 16.4796, 32.9564, 62.0732, 3.7047, 13.8828, 31.6088, 60.1141, 3.3247, 45.0796, 13.7862, 26.4498, 93.6806, 10.3245, 62.5157, 10.9833, 42.5908, 37.3208, 27.4115, 84.1648, 13.9058, 13.9065, 67.8918, 27.9075, 3.6116, 10.9091, 41.0988, 24.2177, 50.2762, 61.3869, 15.5915, 27.6536, 0.7993, 22.9483, 22.3393, 88.1832, 25.1604, 18.3625, 15.7212, 56.9646, 4.0434, 11.8431, 56.0613, 32.5472, 97.8757, 21.8233, 14.8162, 38.8259, 20.5676, 72.7201, 17.7987, 35.8117, 15.1699, 17.0359, 14.0621, 35.9655, 11.9095, 10.5691, 23.3259, 16.1746, 10.1936, 12.5084, 24.1494, 16.4727, 21.0687, 15.7495, 28.8929, 11.0135, 13.3133, 14.6639, 50.1304, 21.0346, 5.1604, 53.5107, 20.0712, 41.5111, 12.1633, 74.3263, 17.7904, 17.1684, 25.3977, 21.5871, 21.9332, 22.6674, 36.6634, 99.1179, 15.3213, 16.3999, 12.0147, 57.5163, 4.2062, 17.3874, 10.7132, 17.4919, 17.8457, 29.3538, 26.1468, 75.1234, 16.4368, 21.6191, 61.1394, 12.9972, 73.5746, 72.5788, 41.6835, 39.9912, 20.1648, 11.7097, 11.5203, 36.7387, 5.0694, 30.8129, 12.0922, 22.5419, 12.3569, 54.6776, 28.3561, 26.1219, 44.7455, 1.3281, 46.5064, 13.6016, 23.5483, 11.7151, 44.3669, 3.2577, 75.0943, 10.8634, 14.8226, 45.7661, 19.7319, 30.7981, 3.5965, 47.8161, 14.5996, 39.4484, 13.0693, 24.9947, 97.4253, 76.7901, 73.1183, 4.0922]
solutionPercentages = [99.2537, 99.8467, 96.4718, 99.6637, 99.6633, 97.1289, 9.7373, 99.5126, 97.3251, 96.0545, 99.6756, 75.6587, 61.1496, 96.7575, 97.1969, 96.5258, 99.7409, 99.8641, 99.8821, 98.5401, 99.7833, 99.6314, 99.7899, 99.9117, 99.5754, 99.5868, 99.7919, 99.9127, 0.0001, 99.7297, 40.8438, 99.8559, 99.6591, 99.8917, 99.3622, 0.0001, 0.0001, 99.4828, 0.0001, 99.8559, 0.0001, 0.0001, 99.6714, 9.9635, 99.8744, 93.8854, 67.3692, 96.3229, 98.4899, 66.9173, 98.2533, 99.8318, 73.9904, 99.8431, 6.2614, 97.2776, 96.0938, 71.9457, 99.9211, 96.1596, 99.8405, 99.6314, 95.4566, 98.4786, 99.8217, 96.1014, 99.0391, 94.6034, 99.8403, 99.9093, 9.8096, 97.8549, 98.7041, 19.9098, 86.3154, 21.5302, 99.2769, 99.0496, 99.7266, 99.8602, 86.7925, 96.3197, 99.9226, 9.4447, 97.9722, 50.4884, 92.2358, 87.4311, 74.2156, 97.8819, 93.2483, 96.3186, 77.9828, 80.2446, 47.1835, 40.8011, 90.5123, 85.7852, 9.8074, 95.9032, 98.5906, 12.5081, 97.0264, 9.9166, 73.6486, 97.8634, 8.4403, 97.7592, 97.9933, 95.8486, 49.7977, 95.1031, 76.1712, 96.1552, 89.0059, 79.6172, 96.7383, 90.8518, 95.8096, 98.2061, 96.3314, 97.5753, 97.9857, 9.0739, 66.9977, 86.5744, 76.8124, 8.6195, 81.3285, 91.0891, 87.3345, 65.3729, 86.7354, 89.9558, 3.1401, 83.4993, 75.1529, 83.5419, 78.3002, 89.8564, 82.2419, 19.3794, 88.2163, 87.9032, 97.8686, 95.0742, 12.3542, 84.7324, 99.4753, 76.1753, 99.5386, 99.8664, 85.7785, 9.9933, 99.7167, 99.9328, 74.4693, 99.7531, 99.0579, 99.5994, 99.7785, 19.2743, 54.7251, 91.7269, 99.5033, 98.9247, 97.6214, 0.0001, 97.7027, 98.6832, 98.4691, 98.9759, 99.7087, 99.9244, 99.4908, 82.1103, 67.6125, 78.2363, 93.5725, 91.5612, 99.8865, 68.5426, 79.0635, 76.8951, 99.3555, 98.9196, 6.1157, 75.8655, 83.8525, 86.1269, 83.3388, 96.1854, 87.1961, 81.7453, 9.2689, 95.2765, 9.0809, 99.8599]

avgSuccess = sum(avgSolutionPercentages)/len(trajectoryIds)

y = solutionPercentages

#Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(y)
ax.set_ylabel('Number of Motions (Total: '+ str(len(trajectoryIds)) + ')')
ax.set_xlabel('Planning Solution (%)')
ax.set_title('Planning Success Rate (Avg: ' + str(round(avgSuccess,2)) + '%)')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

So I found out how to make the values on the x axis more precise: I changed `ax.hist(y)` to `ax.hist(y, bins = 1000)`. But that didn't really work out well either:
[image: Bad Plot]
So now I need to:

1. get rid of the empty space between my bars (is there a way to get rid of these empty x values?)
2. while keeping all bars at the same width
3. change the precision anytime, e.g., from 1 to 0,01 step for each bar

Just any suggestions on how to make the plot (and code) look better are much appreciated :) Maybe it's not the .hist function that's best for this...but I don't know any better - failed doing this with a bar chart so far :(

Comment: In general you need to use the `bins` argument of `hist` to customize your bins. Since the code in the question is not runnable and is not a [mcve], this is all I can say for now.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Sorry, fixed it - now it should be copy pastable!

Comment: what do you mean by "get rid of the empty space between my bars"? the empty space is meaningful in that it indicates that no values in the histogram fall within that bin.

Comment: @csunday95 Not meaningful for my purposes

Comment: so are you thinking [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29257130/3916223) but for a histogram?

Comment: @csunday95 that graph looks bad, no I'm looking for something like a regular bar chart. But I don't know how to group the data I need for it, like the histogram did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

trajectoryIds = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0, 21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0, 28.0, 29.0, 30.0, 31.0, 32.0, 33.0, 34.0, 35.0, 36.0, 37.0, 38.0, 39.0, 40.0, 41.0, 42.0, 43.0, 44.0, 45.0, 46.0, 47.0, 48.0, 49.0, 50.0, 51.0, 52.0, 53.0, 54.0, 55.0, 56.0, 57.0, 58.0, 59.0, 60.0, 61.0, 62.0, 63.0, 64.0, 65.0, 66.0, 67.0, 68.0, 69.0, 70.0, 71.0, 72.0, 73.0, 74.0, 75.0, 76.0, 77.0, 78.0, 79.0, 80.0, 81.0, 82.0, 83.0, 84.0, 85.0, 86.0, 87.0, 88.0, 89.0, 90.0, 91.0, 92.0, 93.0, 94.0, 95.0, 96.0, 97.0, 98.0, 99.0, 100.0, 101.0, 102.0, 103.0, 104.0, 105.0, 106.0, 107.0, 108.0, 109.0, 110.0, 111.0, 112.0, 113.0, 114.0, 115.0, 116.0, 117.0, 118.0, 119.0, 120.0, 121.0, 122.0, 123.0, 124.0, 125.0, 126.0, 127.0, 128.0, 129.0, 130.0, 131.0, 132.0, 133.0, 134.0, 135.0, 136.0, 137.0, 138.0, 139.0, 140.0, 141.0, 142.0, 143.0, 144.0, 145.0, 146.0, 147.0, 148.0, 149.0, 150.0, 151.0, 152.0, 153.0, 154.0, 155.0, 156.0, 157.0, 158.0, 159.0, 160.0, 161.0, 162.0, 163.0, 164.0, 165.0, 166.0, 167.0, 168.0, 169.0, 170.0, 171.0, 172.0, 173.0, 174.0, 175.0, 176.0, 177.0, 178.0, 179.0, 180.0, 181.0, 182.0, 183.0, 184.0, 185.0, 186.0, 187.0, 188.0, 189.0, 190.0, 191.0, 192.0, 193.0, 194.0, 195.0, 196.0, 197.0, 198.0]
avgSolutionPercentages = [20.6256, 99.1448, 15.6764, 21.8231, 16.3733, 17.7502, 20.0055, 86.6873, 11.3105, 15.6693, 10.3449, 81.8921, 11.6745, 92.6031, 11.8787, 23.0229, 37.9636, 2.3903, 15.1727, 14.7088, 10.0426, 59.6758, 8.0042, 12.4174, 10.0585, 46.0567, 90.2376, 98.3273, 52.8645, 49.3027, 62.4136, 32.6199, 19.0642, 10.3319, 74.6157, 22.5771, 22.4118, 11.2017, 16.5053, 11.2021, 30.8376, 24.5255, 83.1072, 10.1529, 14.3991, 46.3459, 16.2137, 4.5773, 44.9549, 1.0719, 76.5605, 42.6589, 13.6209, 34.2856, 1.3574, 29.0465, 66.8146, 16.4796, 32.9564, 62.0732, 3.7047, 13.8828, 31.6088, 60.1141, 3.3247, 45.0796, 13.7862, 26.4498, 93.6806, 10.3245, 62.5157, 10.9833, 42.5908, 37.3208, 27.4115, 84.1648, 13.9058, 13.9065, 67.8918, 27.9075, 3.6116, 10.9091, 41.0988, 24.2177, 50.2762, 61.3869, 15.5915, 27.6536, 0.7993, 22.9483, 22.3393, 88.1832, 25.1604, 18.3625, 15.7212, 56.9646, 4.0434, 11.8431, 56.0613, 32.5472, 97.8757, 21.8233, 14.8162, 38.8259, 20.5676, 72.7201, 17.7987, 35.8117, 15.1699, 17.0359, 14.0621, 35.9655, 11.9095, 10.5691, 23.3259, 16.1746, 10.1936, 12.5084, 24.1494, 16.4727, 21.0687, 15.7495, 28.8929, 11.0135, 13.3133, 14.6639, 50.1304, 21.0346, 5.1604, 53.5107, 20.0712, 41.5111, 12.1633, 74.3263, 17.7904, 17.1684, 25.3977, 21.5871, 21.9332, 22.6674, 36.6634, 99.1179, 15.3213, 16.3999, 12.0147, 57.5163, 4.2062, 17.3874, 10.7132, 17.4919, 17.8457, 29.3538, 26.1468, 75.1234, 16.4368, 21.6191, 61.1394, 12.9972, 73.5746, 72.5788, 41.6835, 39.9912, 20.1648, 11.7097, 11.5203, 36.7387, 5.0694, 30.8129, 12.0922, 22.5419, 12.3569, 54.6776, 28.3561, 26.1219, 44.7455, 1.3281, 46.5064, 13.6016, 23.5483, 11.7151, 44.3669, 3.2577, 75.0943, 10.8634, 14.8226, 45.7661, 19.7319, 30.7981, 3.5965, 47.8161, 14.5996, 39.4484, 13.0693, 24.9947, 97.4253, 76.7901, 73.1183, 4.0922]
solutionPercentages = [99.2537, 99.8467, 96.4718, 99.6637, 99.6633, 97.1289, 9.7373, 99.5126, 97.3251, 96.0545, 99.6756, 75.6587, 61.1496, 96.7575, 97.1969, 96.5258, 99.7409, 99.8641, 99.8821, 98.5401, 99.7833, 99.6314, 99.7899, 99.9117, 99.5754, 99.5868, 99.7919, 99.9127, 0.0001, 99.7297, 40.8438, 99.8559, 99.6591, 99.8917, 99.3622, 0.0001, 0.0001, 99.4828, 0.0001, 99.8559, 0.0001, 0.0001, 99.6714, 9.9635, 99.8744, 93.8854, 67.3692, 96.3229, 98.4899, 66.9173, 98.2533, 99.8318, 73.9904, 99.8431, 6.2614, 97.2776, 96.0938, 71.9457, 99.9211, 96.1596, 99.8405, 99.6314, 95.4566, 98.4786, 99.8217, 96.1014, 99.0391, 94.6034, 99.8403, 99.9093, 9.8096, 97.8549, 98.7041, 19.9098, 86.3154, 21.5302, 99.2769, 99.0496, 99.7266, 99.8602, 86.7925, 96.3197, 99.9226, 9.4447, 97.9722, 50.4884, 92.2358, 87.4311, 74.2156, 97.8819, 93.2483, 96.3186, 77.9828, 80.2446, 47.1835, 40.8011, 90.5123, 85.7852, 9.8074, 95.9032, 98.5906, 12.5081, 97.0264, 9.9166, 73.6486, 97.8634, 8.4403, 97.7592, 97.9933, 95.8486, 49.7977, 95.1031, 76.1712, 96.1552, 89.0059, 79.6172, 96.7383, 90.8518, 95.8096, 98.2061, 96.3314, 97.5753, 97.9857, 9.0739, 66.9977, 86.5744, 76.8124, 8.6195, 81.3285, 91.0891, 87.3345, 65.3729, 86.7354, 89.9558, 3.1401, 83.4993, 75.1529, 83.5419, 78.3002, 89.8564, 82.2419, 19.3794, 88.2163, 87.9032, 97.8686, 95.0742, 12.3542, 84.7324, 99.4753, 76.1753, 99.5386, 99.8664, 85.7785, 9.9933, 99.7167, 99.9328, 74.4693, 99.7531, 99.0579, 99.5994, 99.7785, 19.2743, 54.7251, 91.7269, 99.5033, 98.9247, 97.6214, 0.0001, 97.7027, 98.6832, 98.4691, 98.9759, 99.7087, 99.9244, 99.4908, 82.1103, 67.6125, 78.2363, 93.5725, 91.5612, 99.8865, 68.5426, 79.0635, 76.8951, 99.3555, 98.9196, 6.1157, 75.8655, 83.8525, 86.1269, 83.3388, 96.1854, 87.1961, 81.7453, 9.2689, 95.2765, 9.0809, 99.8599]

avgSuccess = sum(avgSolutionPercentages)/len(trajectoryIds)

y = solutionPercentages

BIN_COUNT = 15
BAR_WIDTH = 0.75

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# use numpy histogram so we can perform filtering
hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(y, bins=BIN_COUNT)
# so we can remove bins with zero entries
non_zero = np.nonzero(hist)
# take only entries where bin is non-zero
hist = hist[non_zero]
bin_edges = bin_edges[non_zero]
# generate labels based on bin edge values (maybe use centers?)
x_ticks = [str(int(edge)) for edge in bin_edges]
indices = np.arange(len(bin_edges))

plt.bar(indices, hist, BAR_WIDTH, align='center')
plt.xticks(indices, x_ticks)
ax.set_ylabel('Number of Motions (Total: '+ str(len(trajectoryIds)) + ')')
ax.set_xlabel('Planning Solution (%)')
ax.set_title('Planning Success Rate (Avg: ' + str(round(avgSuccess,2)) + '%)')
plt.show()
```

which produces the plot

[image: plot produced by above code]

Comment: well.. that is at least ambiguous. Because one is not able to read from the graphics the amount of occurances per "Planning solution"-range. So just make sure not to ever hand-in or publish such figure.

Comment: One could adjust the label list I create to include the lower and upper bound of the range

Comment: @csunday95 I don't quite understand why I don't see a bar for 99% or 100%, when I set the BIN_COUNT to 100. I thought then I would see the rounded values...e.g., for the first two values in solutionPercentages

Answer (score 1):

You may use some nonlinear dependence of the bin width, e.g.

```
b  = 5
bins = (np.linspace(np.min(y)**b, np.max(y)**b))**(1/b)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(y, bins=bins, edgecolor="k")
```

[image]

Or you may define the bins completely customized, e.g. use a bin width of 10 up to 60 and then use a bin width of 5 till 90, finally use a bin with of 1 till 100.

```
bins = np.concatenate((np.linspace(0,60,7),
                       np.linspace(60,90,7),
                       np.linspace(90,100,11)))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(y, bins=bins, edgecolor="k")
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I didn't ask precisely enough! I don't want different widths of the bars (and no zero values like before 60 in the first and 40 in your second pic), I edited the main points on the bottom of my question, hope it's clearer now.

Comment: I don't quite understand the issue then. E.g. the gap between 30 and 40% in the second picture simply comes from the fact that there is no data between 30 and 40. No data = no occurance, hence the histogram is 0 for that bin.

Comment: yes, that's exactly my goal - to only show values on the x-axis that are above zero, leave everything else out

Comment: but I will try out your second approach tmrw with different values, if I find one I like I'll accept your answer!